# Display selected text file from dropdown list in html page

Tags: php

Good Day Everyone
I have looked around and found some very helpful hints and code to populate my dropdown list with availible text files in a directory, my problem is I would like to display the contents of the text file which is a comma delimited file into a table with coloums. This will be on a linux server. My question is: can this really be so difficult? I'm using scandir to check for txt files and populate the dropdown list, so how would the selected file be displayed? I will put up the code as soon as I can, I'm just asking if this is possible and if it is, where should I start? PHP?Javascripting?
Thanks for any input!

Comment: Reading the file content server-side will be a little easier. PHP’s `fgetcsv` function can be used to easily read a line of comma-separated values from a text file into an array. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Thanks for the link, will work through it!